# ACPI BIOS Error and Ubuntu Freezing 18.04.3

Tags: boot, drivers, 18.04, nvidia, acpi

I keep getting this error when Ubuntu boots

> ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure Creating [_SB.PCI0.XHC.RHUB.SS10. AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20181213/dswload2-324

Then, if I click on settings or Mozilla it will freeze and I have to reboot the computer. I read somewhere this could be due to my NVIDIA GeForce Drivers. Here are my computer specs:

- HP Omen Laptop
- Processor: Intel Core i7-8750H
- BIOS Version: AMI F.05
- Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

If anymore information is needed, just let me know...